# which one select after publish webapi

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, asp.net-web-api, cloud

I am working with asp.net MVC with web API

I create an account in Microsoft azure

my API successfully publish but I don't know which one is select from below

[image]

then I click the link and display below 2 part one is deployment center and quick start I don't know which one is select

[image]

what should I do next?

help

Comment: What do you *want* to do next?  Have you tried to access the service to test it?  Either in code by consuming the API or using a tool like Postman to manually interact with the API?  It's not really clear to me what the exact problem is.  It sounds like you've successfully published your API.  The next step is probably to test it.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. For any specific problem you are having please include a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Please also read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask. Make sure that your questions are specific and not overly broad, see also https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic. Also, be sure to take the stackoverflow.com/tour (you get a badge!)

Comment: @David yes I test in postman and status code is 200 OK but the issue is not proper output

Comment: @Rahul: If there's a problem then you'll need to focus on that.  We don't know what your test is, we don't know what your API does, or what result you're getting, or what result you're expecting, etc.  Please read [ask] and its linked resources for tips and information on how to ask a question.  In order to help we'll need information about the problem.

Comment: @Rahul, can you post the end point that you are using in Postman? at least the controller name and the action method name

Answer (score 0):

By default, Azure provides us a simple page hostingstart.html when you create App Service. It's the default page when you get redirected when you access the url.

And, I understand you have published the .Net Framework - Web API. And, you clicked on the App Service and navigated to the root which is expected.

Now, you need to type-in the Controllername/Actionmethod name which should look something as shown below.

https://webapiazuredemo.azurewebsites.net/Home/Index

Can you show the folder structure of the app?

Update: It looks like the database was not created in Azure and so the APIs were throwing an error. Once you create database and it's objects properly in Azure, change the connection string in the code. It should work after that.

Comment: https://webapiazuredemo.azurewebsites.net/api/emps/1 then give an error No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'https://webapiazuredemo.azurewebsites.net/api/1'.</Message> please plese help

Comment: webapiazuredemo.azurewebsites.net/api/emps/1 I already try this but give an error

Comment: what should I do next? help

Comment: can you show the definition of the controller class and the action method function?

Comment: And, Can you check if Application Insights is showing any error?

Comment: It looks like you are using Entity Framework. Are you using Azure SQL Database?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219410/discussion-between-rahul-and-prawin).